# Getting error on executing prepared statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have code as follows which is giving me error on prepared statement line:

homepage.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="list">
            <li><h3><a href="#">tops</a></h3></li>
            <li><h3><a href="#">suits</a></h3></li>
            <li><h3><a href="#">jeans</a></h3></li>
            <li><h3><a href="newpage.php?name=women">more</a></h3></li>
            </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

newpage.php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'shop');

   if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
      }
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
$lcSearchVal=$_GET['name'];
//echo "hi";
$lcSearcharr=explode("-",$lcSearchVal);
$result=count($lcSearchVal);
//echo $result;



$parts = array();
$parts1=array();
foreach( $lcSearcharr as $lcSearchWord ){
    $parts[] = '`PNAME` LIKE "%'.mysqli_real_escape_string($lcSearchWord).'%"';
    $parts1[] = '`TAGS` LIKE "%'.$lcSearchWord.'%"';
    //$parts[] = '`CATEGORY` LIKE "%'.$lcSearchWord.'%"';
}
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM xml where ('.implode ('AND',?).')");
$stmt->bind_Param("s",$parts);

$list=array();
if ($stmt->execute()) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $list[]=$row;
  }
}


    $stmt->close();

    $mysqli->close();
foreach($list as $array)
{
?>
            <div class="image">
<img src="<?php echo $array['IMAGEURL']?>" width="200px" height="200px"/></a>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

SQL query in the php file is not getting executed. I'm getting the following error:

> mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

I am not able to correct the error, I have tried a lot.

Comment: I would suggest echo-ing out the SELECT statement and post the results of that so we can see the entire query put together.

Comment: mysqli and mysql mixed up ...

Comment: i am getting boolean false after printing select statement sir.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's just as it says. I.E. the $parts array has more than one element in it :)

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman-How many parameters i need to give there in bind function sir.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$parts[] = '`PNAME` LIKE "%'.mysql_real_escape_string($lcSearchWord).'%"';
```

to

```
$parts[] = '`PNAME` LIKE "%'.mysqli_real_escape_string($lcSearchWord).'%"';
```